# Spring Boot application starts slow with mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb

I have a Spring Boot application, usually I use H2 database to run the app during development. But sometimes I need Mariadb to try things on. And when I start it with this separate profile the app runs VERY SLOW. I took a look with SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; command from mysql client and figured out that that is schema creation that takes so much time. Basically it's all that CREATE TABLE ... and ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT statements(we use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`). I mean, we have a lot of tables(≈180),but still, very inconvenient to wait about 2 minutes for application to start.
Does anyone have an idea about how it could be improved? Is there a way maybe to tell Hibernate to create schema with several parallel db connections somehow?

Comment: It's usually a **really** bad idea to let hibernate create and/or execute your DDL. In particular the day someone forgets that the value  was changed to `create-drop` for a 'quick test' and deploys to production. Manage your updates using something like flyweight or liquibase.

Comment: I agree with @Augusto. Sounds like you have a pretty big app and I think its time to get serious about how you migrate your db changes to qa/prod etc environments/across the developers. Use tools like liquibase/flyway instead of recreating the whole schema + manually running DDL statements.

Comment: While InnoDB is indeed not very fast when it comes to creating tables it should not take between 0.5s and 1s for that. Does this schema make use of partitioned tables? That would indeed slow things down even further as internally every partition is actually an InnoDB table by itself, so multiplying number of tables by number of partitions ...

If this is really for basic tests only, and does not need to be crash safe, then using MyISAM instead of InnoDB might speed things up quite a bit for DDL

Comment: @Augusto. The issue is completely not about that. We already have Flyway plugged-in and we never touch ddl-auto property neither for production nor for development. It is not about managing my updates! Where did I say I need to manage my updates?! It's just about convenience. It is much more convenient to connect with mysql client to DB while app is running and try things out during development (It is a bit harder to connect to in-memory DB of H2 without additional mumbo jumbo). But the problem is that with mysql profile the app starts really slow.

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe. Thanks for your response. I am not sure what is "partitioned tables " but I am 100% sure we do not use it. I'll give it a try with MyISAM later, thanks. This is only for development purposes, I do not care how fast it starts on production. On production all tables are already up and managed by Flyway. So, as I've said the app starts about 2 minutes and 60% of it takes the schema creation. Next time I run the app it starts really fast as it does not have to create tables.

Comment: If you don't need hibernate to modify your schema, then the value should be set to none `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`. That will skip completely the verification of the schema.

Comment: @Augusto, then how would that schema appear when I run the app on clean test DB?